# Lambdas, local types, and global namespace

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, argument-dependent-lookup

This minimal program

```
template <typename X>
void foo (X x)
{
    bar (x);
}

template <typename X>
void bar (X x)
{
}

int main ()
{
    foo ([]{});
}
```

compiles with gcc (4.8.5 and 5.3) and fails to compile with clang (3.7)

My analysis is as follows.

`bar` is used in `foo` and declared after `foo`, so it is not visible at `foo` definition point. The only way `bar` can be found at `foo` instantiation point is via argument-dependent lookup.

The only argument to both `foo` and `bar` is a lambda defined in `main`.

Apparently gcc regards its type as declared in the global namespace, while clang does not. Thus, gcc can find `bar` via ADL and clang cannot.

Same thing happens when we use a type defined locally in `main`:

```
int main ()
{
    struct K{};
    foo (K());     // gcc compiles, clang complains
}
```

It looks like gcc is in the wrong here. The type of the lambda according to the standard is *unnamed* (expr.prim.lambda/3), so it should not belong to any namespace. The local type supposedly shouldn't belong to the global namespace either.

Is the analysis correct? Is this a known gcc bug?

This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231313/function-works-when-not-in-namespace-else-it-breaks).

Comment: So, the short version is "does the type of a local lambda belong to a namespace, and if so which one?"  And a secondary implied "does the type of a lambda at file/namespace/class scope belong to a namespace, and if so which one?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC is correct, per the resolution of [DR1690/1691](http://wg21.link/cwg1691).

[[expr.prim.lambda]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#4):

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope,
>   or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*.
>   [ *Note*: This determines the set of namespaces and classes associated
>   with the closure type ([basic.lookup.argdep]). The parameter types of
>   a *lambda-declarator* do not affect these associated namespaces and
>   classes.  — *end note* ]

[[basic.lookup.argdep]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2):

> If `T` is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are:
>   the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its
>   direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the
>   innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes.

The innermost enclosing namespace of the closure type at issue is the global namespace, so the global namespace is an associated namespace.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like a new wording in C++14. My copy of C++11 draft says *Its associated namespaces are the namespaces of which its associated classes are members.* Both compilers however give the same result with -std=c++11 and -std=c++14.

Answer (score 2):

GCC is wrong here. It finds `bar()` via ADL even though `[]{}` is not a member of the global namespace. Using the same quote T.C. used:

[[expr.prim.lambda]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#4):

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope,
>   or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*.
>   [ *Note*: This determines the set of namespaces and classes associated
>   with the closure type ([basic.lookup.argdep]). The parameter types of
>   a *lambda-declarator* do not affect these associated namespaces and
>   classes.  — *end note* ]

It's easy to see this by intentionally introducing an error. In GCC:

```
auto f = -[]{};

int main ()
{
    foo (f);
}

error: no match for 'operator-' (operand type is '<lambda()>')

int main ()
{
    foo (-[]{});
}

no match for 'operator-' (operand type is 'main()::<lambda()>')
```

On the other hand, if we move the lambda declaration to global scope, Clang does not complain:

```
auto f = []{};

int main ()
{
    foo (f);
}
```

FWIW this was reported as [Bug 57433](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57433) for GCC but it's unconfirmed. It contains more examples of programs in which GCC accepts/Clang rejects.